# How / why does Python type hinting syntax work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I have just seen the following example in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#compatibility-with-other-uses-of-function-annotations):

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello ' + name

print(greeting('Martin'))
print(greeting(1))
```

As expected, this does not work in Python 2:

```
  File "test.py", line 1
    def greeting(name: str) -> str:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, it works for Python 3:

```
Hello Martin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(greeting(1))
  File "test.py", line 2, in greeting
    return 'Hello ' + name
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

This was unexpected. It does not really check types yet, as you can see with the following example (it runs, but does not throw an exception):

```
def greeting(name: str) -> int:
    return 'Hello ' + name

print(greeting('Martin'))
```

It seems as if after the `:` has to be the name of a function, but the function seems to be ignored:

```
def aha(something):
    print("aha")
    return something+"!"

def greeting(name: aha, foo) -> int:
    return 'Hello ' + name + foo

print(greeting('Martin', 'ad'))
```

The same seems to be true for the name after `->`.

Is this type hinting syntax using something else (like Java Modeling language makes use of comments)? When was this syntax introduced to Python? Is there a way to do static type checking already with this Syntax? Does it always break Python 2 compatibility?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no type hinting going on here. All you did was provide *annotations*; these were introduced with [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) (only in Python 3, there is no support for this in Python 2); they let you annotate arguments and return values with arbitrary information for later inspection:

```
>>> greeting.__annotations__
{'name': <class 'str'>, 'return': <class 'str'>}
```

They are otherwise not consulted at all here. Instead, the error message you got is from trying to concatenate string and integer values *in the body of the function*:

```
>>> 'Hello ' + 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

It is a custom type error aimed at providing additional information as to why the `str` + `int` concatenation failed; it is thrown by the `str.__add__` method for any type that is not `str`:

```
>>> ''.__add__(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
>>> ''.__add__(True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'bool' object to str implicitly
```

PEP 484 then proposes to make use of those annotations to do actual static type checking with *additional tools*, but as the introduction of the PEP states:

> While these annotations are available at runtime through the usual `__annotations__` attribute, *no type checking happens at runtime*. Instead, the proposal assumes the existence of a separate off-line type checker which users can run over their source code voluntarily. Essentially, such a type checker acts as a very powerful linter.

Emphasis in the original.

The PEP was inspired by existing tools that use PEP 3107 annotations; specifically the [mypy project](http://www.mypy-lang.org/) (which is looping right back by adopting PEP 484), but also the [type hinting support in the PyCharm IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html) and the [pytypedecl project](https://github.com/google/pytypedecl). See Guido van Rossum's [original email kickstarting this effort](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2014-August/028618.html) as well as a [follow-up email](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2014-August/028742.html).

mypy apparently supports Python 2 by preprocessing the annotations, removing them before byte-compiling the source code for you, but you otherwise cannot normally use the syntax Python code meant to work in Python 2.

PEP 484 also describes the use of [stub files](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files), which sit next to the regular Python files; these use the `.pyi` extension and only contain the signatures (with type hints), leaving the main `.py` files annotation free and thus usable on Python 2 (provided you wrote Polyglot Python code otherwise).

Comment: Do you know tools which make use of this to do type checking?

Comment: @moose: PyCharm also supports the annotation syntax, see https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html

Comment: @moose: and a third tool that uses annotations for static type hinting: https://github.com/google/pytypedecl

Comment: @MartijnPieters interesting, I didn't know about that