# In Python, are "type annotations" and "type hints" the same thing?

Tags: python, type-hinting

In Python, are "type annotations" and "type hints" the same thing? If not, what's the difference between them?

Comment: I always thought they are the same thing. If you take a look on the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html, you can see it's talking about "type hints" and "type annotations" as the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can both refer to the same sets of things, namely [the language feature of Python 3.5+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-meaning-of-annotations):

```
class Animal:
    #     *
    name: str

    #                  *       *         type annotations
    def foo(self, bar: baz) -> quux:
        ...
```

and sometimes the Python-2-compatible comment syntax supported by tools like [Mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet.html):

```
x = {6, 7}  # type: Set[int]
```

Comment: The accepted answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029343/whats-the-difference-between-type-hinting-in-3-3-and-3-5) about Python 3 type features disagrees and makes a clear distinction between the two.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund: Note that this question asks about “*type* annotations” and my answer is about what they “can” both refer to – because when both terms come up in practice, they will almost always mean the same thing, technicalities aside.