# What does this syntax mean in python? def json_file_to_dict(_file: str) -> dict:?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def json_file_to_dict(_file: str) -> dict:
```

Does it mean that function returns a dictionary type? As far as I know, python is loosely typed language and it does not enforce you to specify data type of a variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-python-3-5-0  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770412/how-why-does-python-type-hinting-syntax-work

Answer (score 4):

These are type hints. They were introduced in Python 3.5 as part of [PEP 0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

They are essentially a contract  that this function returns a `dict` (and expects `_file` to be an instance of `str`), but they're not strictly enforced. They're also fully optional.

From the PEP:

> While these annotations are available at runtime through the usual `__annotations__` attribute, *no type checking happens at runtime*. Instead, the proposal assumes the existence of a separate off-line type checker which users can run over their source code voluntarily. Essentially, such a type checker acts as a very powerful linter.

Comment: I'm under python 3.4.1 and using for a long, maybe I confuse between function annotation and type hints... What this the point ?

Comment: @AliSAIDOMAR Type hints build upon function annotations, which were introduced in Python 3.0 ([PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)).

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax of type hints. It'll be included in Python 3.5.

For detailed description please refer to [PEP0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).